# Rspec/rails: How to test for sample(x) in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a home page that is pulling random entries from my db using this code (probably not the best way, but it works)

```
def home
  ids = Entry.pluck(:id)
  @random_entries = Entry.find(ids.sample(5))
end
```

Here is the view:

```
<p>Here are 5 random entries:</p>
<% @random_entries.each do |entry| %>
<h3><%= entry.word.capitalize %></h3>
<p>Definition: <%= entry.definition %></p>
<% end %>
```

and so far my test is just:

```
it "should have the content 'Here are 5 random entries'" do
  visit '/'
  expect(page).to have_content('Here are 5 random entries')
end
```

But that test only checks for content that was hard-coded into the view. The controller/view are working as I want them, but I have no test and not quite sure where to begin writing one for this.

How should I be testing that controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could count the number of `h3` tags that are present in the page like this:

```
page.all('h3').count.should eql(5)
```

That will do **if you don't have any other h3 tags anywhere else** in that view.

Comment: Good thinking, this will probably need to be changed, but it will work for now.